# Does the delocalization of p-orbitals ensure conductivity?

Tags: computational-chemistry, orbitals, polymers, conductivity

For example, polyacetylene is a [conjugated system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system), i.e. with de-localized p-orbitals, but accroding to [Chiang et. al. (1977)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.39.1098) polyacetylene is semiconducting, and becomes conductive only when doped with Cl/Br/I/AsF<sub>5</sub>.

Isn't the conjugation alone enough to allow conductivity?

[image: Electrical conductivity of trans-polyacetylene as a function of AsF5 dopant concentration]([source](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.39.1098))

### UPDATE

One reason they mention in the paper is:

> In the idealized situation of a uniform chain, the resulting
>   conduction band would give rise to metallic behavior. However, such a
>   system is unstable with respect to bond alternation, which causes the
>   formation of an energy gap in the electronic spectrum.

But if this is true then (1) how the halogens improve the situation, and (2) why isn't there a similar phenomenon in all conjugated systems?

Comment: longer chain gives smaller bandgap but still non-zero bandgap

Comment: I bet Geoff could give an amazing answer to this if he has the time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delocalized $\pi$ orbitals **do** allow for mobile charges. The catch there is "allow." Just because these systems *can* have mobile charges does not make them *conductive*.

Conductivity can be defined as:
$\sigma = n e \mu$
where $e$ is the charge on an electron, $\mu$ is the charge mobility, and $n$ is the number of charges.

In the case of $doped$ conjugated polymers like you indicate above, the halogen vapors or other dopants *usually* oxidize the polymer and create more charges (i.e., $n$) and the conductivity increases. This ***does*** happen with pretty much every conjugated system I've seen: oxidize or reduce the neutral system and you'll have more charge carriers = greater conductivity. (NB: most conjugated organics are easier to oxidize than reduce, so you get + charges (holes) as the charge carrier, rather than electrons.)

That's the quick explanation as to why adding halogens increases the conductivity -- you get more charge carriers.

Incidentally, there are other ways to increase the charge carriers. Chemical or electrochemical doping usually makes a conductive system, but you can also use electrical bias (e.g., a [field-effect transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-effect_transistor)) or light (i.e., a [photovoltaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_solar_cell)) which will also increase carrier concentrations.

**As to why *trans*-polyacetylene isn't a metal in the first place?**

If we use a simple [particle-in-a-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) model, the difference in energy levels goes to zero as the box becomes very large. This would suggest *trans*-polyacetylene should be a metal (i.e., no band gap).

Consider also the [Hückel model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method) for polyacetylene. We can build up the nearly-infinite system by solving for ethylene, butadiene, etc.

[image]

Notice that the energy gap between levels becomes smaller and smaller. We can plot the HOMO-LUMO gap as a function of chain length:

[image]

The gap becomes smaller and smaller!

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method) even gives the general formulas:

$$E_k = \alpha + 2\beta \cos \frac{k\pi}{(n+1)}$$
$$\Delta E = -4\beta \sin \frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}$$

So both particle in a box and Hückel predict no band gap when $n$ gets very large. Theory predicts a metal!

Why doesn't the *real* polyacetylene behave as a metal. For any one-dimensional system, there will be a [Peierls distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peierls_transition) which lowers the total energy by distorting the geometry (long-short bond alternation) and increasing the band gap.<sup>1</sup>

**In short, a truly one-dimensional metal is impossible, but doped polymers are certainly very good electrical conductors. Record films of *trans*-polyacetlyene have conductivity close to conventional metals.**<sup>2</sup>

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> The long-short bond alternation is the Peierls distortion. It means some electrons are localized (shorter double bonds) and thus lower in energy. This creates a band gap (i.e., lower E for valence band).

<sup>2</sup> The film isn't a 1D material, but the trans-polyacetylene chains are each 1D.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation! 2 things are still unclear to me: (1) why long-short bond alteration causes a band gap, and (2) why polyacetylene film is a 1D material?

Comment: The long-short bond alternation is the Peierls distortion. It means some electrons are localized (shorter double bonds) and thus lower in energy. This creates a band gap (i.e., lower E for valence band). The film isn't a 1D material, but the trans-polyacetylene chains are each 1D.

Comment: Great work! I knew this would be smack-dab in the middle of your area of expertise, and polyacetylene is a classic and important system ([Nobel worthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyacetylene), even!). Towards organic metals!